# What counts as combat for boots of mobility?

Tags: league-of-legends

When out of combat for 5 seconds, [Boots of Mobility](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility) grant +5 move speed.  What counts as being in combat?

Comment: If you were to read the link you posted your question would be answered :)

Comment: A clear definition of "combat" is not found anywhere on that page, and is a frequently asked question in the comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anything that causes damage or a debuf will count as combat. This includes damage you deal and damage dealt to you. So if you exhaust someone then your buff will wear off. As the [Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility) states, "**combat dehancers**" do not count as direct combat.

A **combat dehancer** would be something like Warwicks [Blood Scent](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warwick#Blood_Scent). It reveals you on the map, but does not do any damage or have any other direct negative affects to your character.

As of [V1.0.0.101](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.101) these no longer remove your buff from the boots.

The boots as an item are best used for roamers who need to switch lanes quickly. They are great for ganking because by the time someone calls an MIA you're already in another lane. Shaco is one of the most common champions I see with Boots of Mobility.

Comment: Your answer is far more completed than mine =X So i deleted mine and +1 yours =D

Comment: @MichelAyres Haha, if there is any game I am very familiar with its LoL

Comment: I assume combat dehancer refers to passive abilities, and not actives.  Do you know any other dehancers besides blood scent?

Comment: @Toast I am looking for a clearer definition of "combat dehancer" and hopefully a list of combat dehancing abilities, but nothing yet. :( My guess would be something like Abyssal Scepter would be considered combat dehancing because you don't even have to know someone is present in order to debuf them.

Comment: @Emerica. add Frozen heart too =)

Comment: @MichelAyres Yeah, I think it may be time to conduct SCIENCE to discover a full list of Combat Dehancers. It seems to be something that noone is clear on, so let's make a name for Gaming.SE!

Comment: would something like nidalee's trap slow you down?

Comment: @PeterJessen, Yes, when triggered the trap deals damage, thus putting you in combat.

Comment: what if you are nidalee and someone walks on your trap?

Answer (score 1):

[Boots of Mobility](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility)...

> Will now mark you in combat for receiving/dealing any damage, even if it is absorbed by shields.

Check the Patch History for the item at the bottom of [this page](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility).

Comment: It's encouraged to copy relevant information into your answer, in case the link is unavailable.

Comment: If I could downvote a comment i would, He posted the same page as you did in the question.

Comment: @Brain, not sure why you say that.  This answer fails to explain what combat damage is, and points to an external resource for a "full" explanation (a practice frowned upon here).

Comment: @Toast The definition of combat is receiving/dealing ANY damage. How can I make this more clear?