# Unit "in combat"

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What counts as combat for boots of mobility?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62233/what-counts-as-combat-for-boots-of-mobility)

I would like to know when a unit is consider to be "in combat". Mainly, im interested in knowing how long it takes to get from "in combat" to "out of combat" state.

(Basically, I want to know how the new utility mastery works - the one giving you movespeed when you are out of combat.)

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62233/18146

Comment: This is imo not a duplilcate - boots of mobility states something completely different. They say that after 5 secs out of combat you get the bonus speed.

Answer (score 3):

After 5 seconds of not taking or dealing any damage, your champion is considered "Out of Combat".

This is how Boots of Mobility have worked for a long time.

Comment: Does that include dealing/taking damage from minions, or is it just for champions?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, minions are included.

Comment: Boots of mobility, yes, but how about the new mastery in utility tree?

Comment: @Santhos "After 5 seconds of not taking or dealing any damage, your champion is considered 'Out of Combat' ". It's the *same* as Boots of Mobility, is what I'm saying.